# I have configurated my server to SMTP, But all mails get stuck in Queue

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2003

MY mails dosen't get send out, all mails get stuck in the queue folder, what does this mean,

are there other ports I run thans besides 25?

Comment: This needs to go on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well they got stuck in queue because the provider had blocked port 25